# Edit charts without selecting sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make changes to various graphs using VBA. I recorded a macro that works, but when I try and remove the sheet selection to speed it up, it just gives an error.

Recorded code:

```
Sheets("Div").Select
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Divi").Activate
ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Sheets("Control").Range("G112").Value
```

My code:

```
Worksheets("Div").ChartObjects("Divi").Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = Sheets("Control").Range("G112").Value
```

How can I fix it so that I don't need to select each chart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code that works to me

```
    With Worksheets("Div").ChartObjects("Divi").Chart.Axes(xlValue)
        .MaximumScale = Sheets("Control").Range("G112").Value
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you can make your code work. But you can disable screen updating with

`Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

That would speed it up a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using it but want to as fast as possible as it has thousands of charts and workbooks to do.